# Concatenar en una ruta una variable de javascript

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando en laravel, creando una verificacion para poder eliminar un registro
El codigo JS

```
function confirmModal( $func,$id)
{
                var message = "guardar";
                if ($func == "eliminar")
                    message = "eliminar";
                bootbox.confirm({
                    message: "¿Desea " + message + " el registro?",
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: {
                            label: 'Si',
                            className: 'btn-success'
                        },
                        cancel: {
                            label: 'No',
                            className: 'btn-danger'
                        }
                    },
                    callback: function (result) {
                        if ( result )
                        {
                             document.location.href="{!! route('admin.users.destroy', '$id' )!!}"; //esta es la ruta para laravel, pero no puedo concatenar el id que le paso a través de onclick 

                        }
                        $('.modal-open .modal').css({"overflow-x": "hidden", "overflow-y": "auto"});
                    }
                });

}
```

..
alguna solucion para mi problema..
De antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

le estas pasando una variable de php a una funcion escrita en javascript

intenta de esta forma , pero organizalo a tu conveniencia porque se esta seteando id y func fuera de la funcion

```
var id = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
var func = "<?php echo $func; ?>";

function confirmModal( func,id)
{



    var message = "guardar";
                if (func == "eliminar")
                    message = "eliminar";
                bootbox.confirm({
                    message: "¿Desea " + message + " el registro?",
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: {
                            label: 'Si',
                            className: 'btn-success'
                        },
                        cancel: {
                            label: 'No',
                            className: 'btn-danger'
                        }
                    },
                    callback: function (result) {
                        if ( result )
                        {
                             document.location.href="{!! route('admin.users.destroy', 'id' )!!}"; //esta es la ruta para laravel, pero no puedo concatenar el id que le paso a través de onclick 

                        }
                        $('.modal-open .modal').css({"overflow-x": "hidden", "overflow-y": "auto"});
                    }
                });

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero sucede casi lo mismo, toma como un String  'id' y no como un valor  integer

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes una ruta así:

```
Route::get( '/user/destroy/{id}', 'TuControlador@tuFuncion')->name('admin.users.destroy');
```

Tú código javascript quedaría así:

```
function confirmModal( $func,$id)
{
                var message = "guardar";
                if ($func == "eliminar")
                    message = "eliminar";
                bootbox.confirm({
                    message: "¿Desea " + message + " el registro?",
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: {
                            label: 'Si',
                            className: 'btn-success'
                        },
                        cancel: {
                            label: 'No',
                            className: 'btn-danger'
                        }
                    },
                    callback: function (result) {
                        if ( result )
                        {
                             document.location.href="{{ route('admin.users.destroy', ['id' => $id] ) }}"; //esta es la ruta para laravel, pero no puedo concatenar el id que le paso a través de onclick 

                        }
                        $('.modal-open .modal').css({"overflow-x": "hidden", "overflow-y": "auto"});
                    }
                });

}
```

NOTA: Para poder ejecutar código php dentro de un script, el código javascript debe de estar dentro del archivo `.blade.php`

Comment: si el codigo js esta dentro del .blade.php,  pero aun sigue sin concatenar, al enviar directamente la variable $id, lo toma como un string y no toma encuenta el valor integer que se le envia..
de todos modos gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir la parte a la que te refieres de que lo toma como string?, si con eso te refieres a que por ejemplo, dado el `$id = 1` cuando lo imprimes te sale así: `"1"` y no así `1`, lo que puedes hacer es ponerle un `intval($id)`

Comment: document.location.href="{!! route('admin.users.destroy', '$id' )!!}";
la variable $id, lo toma como un string al ponerlo tal cual
pero al tratar de convertir a entero, sucede un error es decir
al enviar la ruta, como pide un valor que en este caso es un ID, y al usar las ' ', en la ruta generada muestra esto
admin/users/%24id/destroy
y en ese campo (%24id) debería estar el valor del ID

Comment: @LuisAguilar Pues yo creo que es más problema de alguna parte del código que no especificas,  porque no hay de otra, tu ruta debería de quedar así {{ route(‘admin.users.destroy’, [‘id’ => $id]) }}

Comment: html: 
<a  onclick="confirmModal( 'eliminar',{{$user->id}}); "  class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar" >
js
--
document.location.href="{{route('admin.users.destroy',  ['id' => $id])}}";
--
error 
Undefined variable: id

Comment: @LuisAguilar Tu variable $id no la estás enviando a la vista

Comment: envio todos los datos, incluyendo el id..
oh como puedo enviar??
 public function index()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.users.index')->with('users',$users); 
    }
envio con eso

Comment: Pues entonces sería así “{{ route(‘admin.users.destroy’, [‘id’ => “+$id+”) }}”